# Case Statement embedded in NVL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to setup the below logic in as a divisor. I need to use NVL() to avoid the divide by zero error. I need to get a distinct count of the case statement.

Here is what I have:

```
(NVL(COUNT(DISTINCT 
           CASE WHEN ({field1} = 'a' OR {field1} = 'b' OR 
                      {field1} = 'c' OR {field1} = 'd') AND 
                      ({field2} = 'a' OR {field2} = 'b') AND 
                      ({field3} > TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
                THEN 1 END), 1))
```

There is something wrong with my syntax but cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The code is so clearly Oracle that I changed the tag.  You shoudl explain what you want to do, because the code does not look right.  For instance, are you aware that `count(distinct)` *never* returns `NULL`?

Comment: And then if you're doing a distinct count on a value of 1 without an else, then 1 counted distinctly will always be 1 or 0 (if none are 1) .  The NVL does nothing to change 0 to 1. but if you want the zero to be 1, then this would ALWAYS return 1.  So to simplify just put `1`...  yeah... what are you after?

Comment: I should have clarified in my post that I am very new to SQL, so I was not aware that this was Oracle, so thanks for changing the tag.

What I want to do is take a count of distinct values in a column using the case statement. I then want to use that count as the divisor of a different statement. I am getting "cannot divide by zero" errors which was why I tried the NVL statement. Thanks.

Comment: You want a distinct count of values in **which** column? In your code you count the number of distinct values of the number 1 (which doesn't make sense, as xQbert pointed out). Also, if you use this as a divisor, in most cases counting **distinct** is wrong from a logical/algebraic point of view. If you could explain the situation in more detail, we can probably help you figure that out first, before worrying about code to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I changed lots of `OR`s to simpler `IN`

```
COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN  field1 IN ('a','b','c','d')
      AND field2 IN ('a','b')
      AND field3  > TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    THEN 1
END)
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` doesn't return null, so removed redundant `NVL`

Now, the above will result is either 0 or 1.

You probably want this without distinct:

```
COUNT(
  CASE
    WHEN  field1 IN ('a','b','c','d')
      AND field2 IN ('a','b')
      AND field3  > TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    THEN 1
END)
```

Since, it is a divisor, it can't be 0, so you'll have to place safeguard for that. One sensible output in case the divisor is 0 is null. One way to achieve that is:

```
case when (expression) <> 0  then dividend/(expression) end
```

Comment: There is no need for `NVL()`. `COUNT()` doesn't return `NULL`

Comment: Took less time than typing a comment on the error on the NVL removal update. (you're quite welcome)  But this doesn't handle the divide by zero error the OP was trying to eliminate. by using NVL in the first place.

Comment: @xQbert - I mostly checked syntax error and other syntax cleaning (and yet left a big one at the end).I think it should be without distinct (coz now it will produce 0 or 1) and some check to change 0 to 1 (or something else) if that is in the result.

Comment: I didn't see any mismatched parentheses, where were they? I do agree that the conditions should be rewritten with `in`, as you have done, I am just curious about the parentheses (did I miss something?)